# UK-Jamaica flights without transiting the USA or Canada

Tags: air-travel, transit, tickets, bookings, flight-search-engines

I am a Nigerian citizen currently in the UK on a student visa with a residence permit valid for 3 years. I am planning a trip to Jamaica in a few days and do not have time to get transit visas for the USA or Canada. How do I find cheap tickets that do not include travel via the USA or Canada and that are to transit visa-free destinations?

Comment: "Cheap tickets" and "in a few days" do not go well together.  It seems the simplest would be to fly direct on British Airways, but that will be expensive.  There are some low-cost airlines flying to Jamaica from continental Europe.  Do you have a Schengen visa?

Comment: Google Flights.  Kayak.  Expedia.  Are you having trouble with any of these?

Comment: No I do not have a schengen Visa, Travelling from England to Germany in transit would I need one?.

Answer (score 2):

Short notice (a few days) + high travel season + Not US/Canada = Expensive Ticket

Routing options in Europe are London Gatwick, Brussels, Cologne, Dusselsdorf, Frankfurt, Munich and Milano.

If you can get yourself to Cologne, Eurowings offers a round trip to Montego Bay for 400 Euros, 6/18-6/25.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. The question is "How do I find out the answer to X?" and you've neither told them how to find out, nor told them the answer to X.

Comment: thank you, I am seeing it now. Germany is a more liberal country, do you know if I would need a visa just for transit?

Comment: @Tola:  See [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area) to figure out whether you need a transit visa in the Schengen area.

Comment: @Tola you will need a regular (type C short-stay) Schengen visa (unless you can book a single ticket from the UK via Germany) because you will have to pass through passport control to pick up and re-check your luggage.  Some people need an "airport transit visa" for transits that don't require passing through passport control, but having a UK residence permit exempts you from that requirement.

Comment: @phoog yes I have seen a ticket(EURO WINGS) London-cologne-jamaica. so It is my understanding I will not need a transit visa correct? Since i have a valid UK student visa.. thank you for your help.

Comment: @Tola to avoid the need for a Schengen visa you must confirm that you do not need to retrieve your luggage in Germany.  Some low-cost airlines would require you to retrieve it.  Check with the airline.